# JCombo Box Searching

Tags: java, swing

Recently i m working on a s/w project which require an editable combo box... At start i attached action Listener whith it but it didnt worked... Then i started searching over document listener which seems to be suitable for this situation

I want to create this

```
-------------------------
a                              //---------- Consider this as a combo box
-------------------------
a  
ab
aba
abca
abdaa          

---------------------
ab                              //---------- Consider this as a combo box
---------------------
ab
aba
abca
abdaa             //- Hints
```

Now i am bit confused how to use document listener with combo box , because every where `JTextComponent` is attached with it.... Please help.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478577/how-to-make-a-text-field-for-searchingwith-tips-like-a-google-search/6479302#6479302).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a perfect example that is very fast: [AutoCompletion](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/source/AutoCompletion.java).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of what you're looking for: [Searchable JComboBox](http://jstomp.sourceforge.net/comboBox/search.html)

Comment: To the point approach, but please give this a try... It work but create a lot problem..... During writing word disappear... Also refresh rate is quit visible, Searching is not strict....